# How to fix the command line shortcut for the Brackets editor?

Tags: command-line, alias

I've installed [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), but if I try to type `brackets` at the command line I get

```
-bash: brackets.sh: command not found
```

I've found that the shell script is located in `/Applications/Brackets.app/Contents/Resources/brackets.sh`. What is the recommended way to fix the problem - do I just define

```
alias brackets=/Application/Brackets.app/Contents/Resources/brackets.sh
```

or should I somehow re-install/update Brackets?

Comment: try ~/Applications/Brackets.app/Contents/MacOS/Brackets